# Does google sheet support functions similar to excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

Does Google Sheets support creating a report similar to the one we can generate using VBA or macros in Excel?
What I mean does Google Sheets let the user generate report display in form something like this, where when the user clicks generate form. new form appear displaying the report.

[image]

Comment: You could research Google Apps Script to create this functionality.

Comment: Look here for some repacements for VBA in google sheet https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-equivalent-of-VBA-for-Google-sheets-or-do-you-use-VBA-there-too